# Resize, crop and SBS duplicate with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

As I have no previous knowledge of video editing, I'm still struggling to get **ffmpeg** to work as I need.

I need to resize **a video of any size and any aspect** ratio to height a of 960px, then crop both sides to get a square of 960x960 where the original image would be centered. And now the tricky part for me, I need to duplicate this square, so they would be side by side as single output video of 1920 x 960 pixels.

It's not supposed to be 3D, only cardboard friendly.

[image: visual explanation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex \
       "[0]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,scale=-1:960,crop=960:960,split[left][right]; \
        [left][right]hstack[sbs]"  -map "[sbs]" -map 0:a? out.mp4
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. You might want to fix the typo though. You missed a '=' after scale command.